# Selecting element by xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriver

Trying to scrape data and select tweets from twitter.com by xpath using selenium web driver. After selecting by copying the xpath it still does not select the supposed data (tweet)

I have tried selecting by elements(HTML and CSS) and ID but still can not get the data. It returns empty.
i also tried copying the exact xpath but still does not select the data. i expect to be able to select tweet body from the page.

this is the html source code of the data i am trying to select

```
<article aria-labelledby="id_wmmsj5dl6ge id7th6l1a5wgh id57zpbbqipvp id6yksnu908 idxczh1kvkiy idasajs7v70lt ider3q96nfdy idnaetiu318m idwvawayq8zm idvl109wu5v9 ide11e46cf6o5 idf6ieztmddj7 id8hjgln6ljnb idecx5c3y8mlk idxr1c6zwm9xl id4k08f14jhcq idy30p00ojq6p id67xzovkwa5c" role="article" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-1ny4l3l r-1udh08x r-1qhn6m8 r-i023vh r-o7ynqc r-6416eg" data-testid="tweet"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-eqz5dr r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2 r-1ny4l3l"><div class="css-1dbjc4n"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-18u37iz"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1iusvr4 r-16y2uox r-ttdzmv"></div></div></div>
```

and this is how i try to select it

```
cards = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article[@data-testid="tweet"]')
print(cards)  # this line to check the content of the "cards" list
card = cards[0]
```

Comment: _`//article[@data-testid="tweet"]`_: I don't see any `<article>` tag in the HTML you shared.

Comment: Nor does it has a  element with the attribute `@data-testid` with the value `tweet`. I think you should put some more time in asking a question

Comment: @undetectedSelenium sorry for the confusion, i have corrected the html code. please let me know what you think

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed sorry for the confusion, i have corrected the html code. please let me know what you think

Comment: @DakillaLord The `<article>` tag is visible now, but what would you do with it? The `<article>` tag and it's descendant none of them seems to be clickable or have any text within them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to collect tweets on the page. so i expect it to output the tweet text. then after collecting the tweeting, i want to extract the data like username, likes and timestamp.